# Disappeared article

Tags: posts

Good morning, one of my clients has a disappeared article from the 'Posts' section of Wordpress. I tried to upload a backup, but everything crashes when I attempt to reload them (I've already contacted the plugin support), so I have no way to restore from a backup.

The client is absolutely certain that the post was duplicated and then published normally; nothing out of the ordinary was done. The post was published on 27/07, but it was only yesterday that the client noticed it was missing.

Does anyone have any ideas where I could start looking for the vanished post?

Thank you.

Comment: What format is the backup? Can you fish the post content out of it any way at all - even if it's just the text to use to reconstruct the post rather than a formatted post to drop straight into your database say

Comment: "the post was duplicated" - so you have a second copy of it somewhere anyway? Can you duplicate that again?

Comment: As to what happened to it, I guess either someone deleted it in the admin site or somehow your site's database got rolled back to a state before the post existed. You can look at the server access logs for /wp-admin/ requests for the first one, or talk to your host if you suspect the database rollback. But it sounds like restoring the post is the priority.